# Hausman test for models with different regressors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I want to know if I can run a Hausman test for Random Effects and First-Difference models with different regressors? For Example:

MODre = X + Y + **Z**

MODfd = X + Y + **C**

Where X, Y, Z, C are some explanatory variables.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hausman test only takes the common variables of both models (and compares them). The test does not tell you anything about the non-common variables as those are not compared and dropped in the test (for most statistic packages).